# Designing an interactive client

Tags: c, sockets, unix, client-server

I'm trying to design a client program that connects to a remote server and sends various messages / request to it and expects responses based on the requests sent (for e.g. send a join message and wait for a response, then either query for some resource or ask for some info etc. in no particular order).

I would like to design the client such that the user can choose any of the possible requests to send after joining the server (after completing one request and getting a response if any it should allow them to carry out further requests or quit). Something like a menu of actions that it returns to each time (while also waiting for any data from the server)? However I can't seem to figure out how to this could be done. Is there a way to do this (preferably without getting into forking/threads)?

Any inputs on this would be really great. TIA

Comment: Wait, are you trying to design a web site? OK my real question is: have you considered HTTP? With e.g. Mongoose on the server side and curl for the client?

Answer (score 2):

I would start off with a simple chat server to get your feel for socket programming. Google Example TCP Chat Server or something, you'll end up with simple examples like this: http://www.cs.ucsb.edu/~almeroth/classes/W01.176B/hw2/examples/tcp-server.c .. once you are able to telnet to your server and read/write to your clients, you should be able to progress from there and perform actions when your clients issue a specific command and that sort of thing.

Comment: Defeating my previous comment, this is actually the way to go. It's lot of fun to design your own protocol.

Comment: Yeah I got the impression that's what he was wanting to do. Although, @source.rar if you are looking to create gui's and that sort of stuff, the way to go is using a web browser as your client, and communicating to your server via http as Tibo suggested. If that's the case, then check out http://libevent.org/ this is one of my favorite C libraries, it makes it very easy to create an embedded web server takes care of all the http protocol stuff for you so all you need to do is write the callbacks to handle the various urls you'll use for your commands.

Comment: Thanks for the example. However what I'm actually looking for is for a some way to be interactive at the client side itself while it also interacts with the server (if that makes any sense :)). Also no GUI's and stuff at least for now (just plain old CLI)

Comment: @source.rar Once you get a grasp on socket programming it'll be evident that you can certainly be interactive on the client while things are going on on the server. By using `select` or similar functions (`epoll`, etc..) you can determine when you need to read/write to your sockets to exchange data with your server, thus allowing you to still be interacting with the user on the client side while you're waiting on data from the server. But you should start off simple and not worry about writing the client until you have your server working with telnet, then you can write your client.